# Doctrine and PDO not giving the same results

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

Okay, the code below I have created to show the issue.
And yes, I appreciate the fact that it should ALL be doctrine and by using PDO it makes the whole doctrine thing kinda pointless.

More importantly though, I am trying to understand why the two don't match up.

Basically, the first PDO query comes back with: 70 row count and 140 Max ID.
The second PDO query returns the same 70 row count and 140 Max ID.
The problem is, the doctrine insert between the two has made it 71 and 141.

Why is the second PDO query note reflecting this?

If I run the query in a separate PHP page or in Workbench, it returns 71/141. It just doesn't within the executing page.

```
$userID = $enUser->getId();
$stmt1 = $this->pdoConnection->getConnection()->prepare('
  SELECT  COUNT(UT.ID) AS UTC,
          MAX(UT.ID) AS UTMID
  FROM    UserThing UT
  WHERE   UT.User_ID = :userID;
' ) or die ( implode( ':', $stmt1->errorInfo(  ) ) );

$stmt1->bindParam( ':userID', $userID, \PDO::PARAM_INT, 11 );
$results = $this->pdoConnection->dbRecSet( $stmt1, false );
$stmt1->closeCursor();
unset($stmt1);
var_dump($results);

$newUserThing = new UserThing();
$newUserThing->setUserThingThings( $enThing );
$newUserThing->setUserThingUsers( $enUser );
$newUserThing->setAttainedDate( new \DateTime() );
$this->em->persist( $newUserThing );
$this->em->flush();
$userThingID = $newUserThing->getId();

echo $userThingID;

$stmt2 = $this->pdoConnection->getConnection()->prepare('
  SELECT  COUNT(UT.ID) AS UTC,
          MAX(UT.ID) AS UTMID
  FROM    UserThing UT
  WHERE   UT.User_ID = :userID;
' ) or die ( implode( ':', $stmt2->errorInfo(  ) ) );
$stmt2->bindParam( ':userID', $userID, \PDO::PARAM_INT, 11 );
$results = $this->pdoConnection->dbRecSet( $stmt2, false );
$stmt2->closeCursor();
unset($stmt2);
var_dump($results);
```

Any ideas why the second PDO query doesn't reflect the DB change, even though Doctrine is able to return the newly inserted ID?

Comment: I tried to recreate this but could not. Are you sure it has nothing to do with the `WHERE   UT.User_ID = :userID;`?

Comment: I have worked out the issue. But you have to wait X amount of time before you can answer your own question. Hopefully what I found out will help others. Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bit which didn't occur to me when making this post, was the fact that my PDO class used a different connection string to the Symfony one.

To be able to support multiple record sets to be returned from a single query, my class used different driver options to the default. So I just ported over the class into Symfony and used it and it worked well for a long time.

That said, doing an insert/update on one connection and reading straight after on another does not work well. That is the issue I found here.

The documentation for Symfony when it comes to PDO driver options is a bit lacking. For anyone facing it, all you need to know is that the PDO constants just need their Integer equivalents in the YML instead.
So you end up with things like this in your app/config/config.yml:

```
options:
    20: true
    3: 1
    1002: "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'"
```

That allowed me to do what I needed to and do it correctly.